# How to Use Chi-Squared Test for Inference about Three-way independence

Tags: chi-squared-test, inference, independence

If I recall correctly, three random variables X, Y, and Z are three-way independent iff these two statements are met:

P(X∩Y∩Z) = P(X)P(Y)P(Z)

X, Y, and Z are all pairwise independent of each other.

In order to test a hypothesis about whether three categorical random variables are three-way independent, would it be okay for me to perform the following tests:

A 3D chi-square test with each of the expected 3d matrix's cells = P(X)P(Y)P(Z) in order to see if there is convincing evidence that condition 1. for three-way independence is met.

Do 3 normal chi-square tests for independence among X-Y, X-Z, and Y-Z to see if there is convincing evidence that condition 2. for three-way independence is met.

Also, is it okay for me to then draw my conclusion based on whether or not there is convincing evidence that both conditions for three-way independence are met?

Comment: No test based on a sample will establish that the variables *are* actually independent. It may sometimes make it pretty clear that they aren't, but since the dependence may be small - smaller than you have the power to detect at some given sample size - you can't obtain "convincing evidence" for independence, since it will be practically indistinguishable from sufficiently small dependence.